# Netbeans - refactor anonymous class to seperate file

Tags: java, class, netbeans, refactoring, netbeans-8

In Netbeans 8.1 in the Java code I have an anononymous inner class that I want to refactor to a named ("normal") class and into a separate file. **How can I do this?**

When I do **Convert Anonymous to Member** it converts the anonymous class to a member class withing the current .java file.

[image: Convert anonymous to member]

[image]
How do I move this now to a separate file? I can do this of course manually but I would like to do it using the IDE.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be a known bug in Netbeans. Further information can be found in:

https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=206422

The last comment (lytles 2016-04-21 23:14:30 UTC) is from April this year, and gives you a workaround:

> the only workaround i can find is to "move inner to outer level", and then "move" the new class (click "To Type") to an existing class. it's far from perfect - the code gets reformatted and the end result is pretty buggy, eg superclass methods get prepended with the class name and don't resolve so i'm then copying and pasting the old code into the new class